# Dervation for optimization

Tags: calculus, derivatives, optimization

Could anyone helps me to derivative the below functions, it is kinda complicated for me:

1- derivative the function in terms of x_0:
\begin{align*}
\sum\nolimits_{f = 1}^{[S/\eta ]} ~~
\frac{{{f^{ - \delta }}}}{{\sum\nolimits_{f = 1}^{F} {{f^{ - \delta }}} }}~~{B}\log _2 \left(1+ A {x_0}^{ -\alpha_L}{e^{ - K({f}){x_0}}}\right)\
\end{align*}

2- derivative the function in terms of \eta:
\begin{align}
\sum_{f=[S/\eta]+1}^{F} \frac{f^{-\delta}}{\sum_{f=1}^{F}{f^{-\delta}}} B\log_2\left(1+C\right) + \sum_{f=1}^{F}\frac{f^{-\delta}}{\sum_{f=1}^{F}{f^{-\delta}}}B\log_2\left(1+A{x_0}^{-\alpha_L}e^{-K(f)x_0}\right)\nonumber&-\lambda\left(S-\sum_{f=1}^{[S/\eta]} b_f\right)\nonumber
\end{align}